# Update from TYPO3 v4.5.0 to v4.5.22

Tags: typo3

Short & Simple question:

I'm currently at a customer who got TYPO3 v 4.5.0 up and running. Can I now update to v4.5.22 directly?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here can you find important upgrading instructions: http://wiki.typo3.org/Upgrade

Yes, in this situation you can do that without upgrading version by version.

You should always check the release notes of each version on http://wiki.typo3.org.